# Проблема с формой смены пароля

Tags: php

всем привет. возникла небольшая проблема, подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить. пишу форму смены пароля, но не появляются ошибки и пароль не меняется. подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так

```
if(isset($data['do_change'])) {
 $user = R::findOne('users', 'login = ?', array($data['login']));
 $errors = array();
 if($user){
  if(password_verify($data['old_password'], $user->password)) {
   // change here
   if($data['new_password_1'] == '') {
    $errors[] = "Введите новый пароль!";
   }
   if($data['new_password_2'] != $data['new_password_1']) {
    $errors[] = 'Повторный пароль введён неверно!';
   }
   if(empty($errors)) {
    $user->password = password_hash($data['new_password_1'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    echo '<div id="success" style="color: green;">Пароль успешно сменён!</div><hr>';
   } else {
    echo '<div id="errors" style="color: red;">' . array_shift($errors) . '</div><hr>';
   } 
  } else {
   $errors[] = "Старый пароль введён неверно";
  }
 }

 if(!empty($errors)) {
  echo '<div id="errors" style="color: red;">' . array_shift($errors) . '</div><hr>';
 }
}
```

Comment: А где сама форма?

Answer (score 0):

Для начала убедитесь что у вас показываются ошибки php, а не тот array error который вы создаете.

Добавьте в шапке файла:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
```

Далее я бы обратил внимание на три места в вашем коде:

```
if($user){
```

Вардампните что-то после этой строки или запишите в файл, чтобы убедится что пользователь определяется и скрипт это условие обрабатывает.

```
if($user){
    var_dump($data['old_password']); // вардамп старого пароля.
```

Следующее место:

```
 if(password_verify($data['old_password'], $user->password)) {
```

password_verify использует сравнение пароля хешу. Т.е. в `$data['old_password']` должен быть пароль в виде 1111, а в `$user->password` закодированная алгоритмом строка. Выведите и то, и то, убедитесь что они соответствуют друг другу.

Вардампните перед этим условием:

```
 var_dump($data['old_password']);
 var_dump($user->password);
 if(password_verify($data['old_password'], $user->password)) {
    echo "соответствуют";
```

Последнее место на которое стоит обратить внимание:

```
   if(empty($errors)) {
    $user->password = password_hash($data['new_password_1'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Я не уверен что за фреймворк/CMS вы используете, но у вас точно так должен записываться новый пароль в БД?

Похоже что здесь просто присваивается к `$user->password` хеш нового пароля.

Соответственно как только скрипт заканчивает обработку никаких записей куда-либо не происходит. Полагаю что данные вы храните в БД, а значит нужно через SQL произвести UPDATE значения пароля пользователя. Возможно в виде какого-то класса или обработчика в соответствии с вашей CMS/фреймворком.